# Python Deque with Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, deque

I was running deque successfully in the following manner to create a track of an object:

```
from collections import deque
...
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])
....
pts.appendleft(center)

# loop over the set of tracked points
for i in range(1, len(pts)):
    # if either of the tracked points are None, ignore
    # them
    if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
        continue

    # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
    # draw the connecting lines
    thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
    cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)
```

So the format of each entry into pts is a set of (x,y) and it keeps a length of whatever "buffer" was set to.

Now, I would like to track a few objects, so "center" is now a numpy array of center points like so:

center = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]

I am having a ton of trouble getting this to work with deque. I would like to make it so pts also keeps track of the separate center points to a length of "buffer".

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: would love some assistance with this

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is following this, I solved it instead by creating a class and method for using deque:

```
    from collections import deque
    import argparse
    parser.add_argument('--buffer', type=int, default=64, help='buffer 
            size for drawing trailing path')
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    class trackDraw():
        def __init__(self):
            #set up buffer size
            self.pts = deque(maxlen=args.buffer)
        
        def updatePts(self,center):
            self.pts.appendleft(center)
    
        def drawPts(self,frame, color):
            for i in range(1, len(self.pts)):
                if self.pts[i-1] is None or self.pts[i] is None:
                    continue
                self.thickness = int(np.sqrt(args.buffer / float(i+1)) * 2)
                cv2.line(frame, self.pts[i-1], self.pts[i], color, self.thickness)
```